# PHP foreach get array key beginning with

Tags: php

I currently loop through the array and collect values into another array.

```
            foreach($percentage_array[$scenario_first] as $type => $value) {

                $first = substr($type,0,$first_letters_count);

                if(strlen($type)==$sc_type) {

                    if($first==$scenario) {

                        $percentages[] = $value;
                        $scenario_array[$type] = $value;
                    }
                }

            }
```

Instead of looping through the array, i want to get all keys that begin with `x` e.g. xaa, xab, xac

So instead i do `$percentage_array[$scenario_first][beginning_with_x]`

How do i do this?

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT**: This is even easier:

```
$filtered_array = array_filter($array, function($key){
    return $key{0} == 'x';
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
```

Giving:

```
array(3) {
  ["xa"]=>
  int(1)
  ["xb"]=>
  int(2)
  ["xd"]=>
  int(4)
}
```

https://3v4l.org/Zri7n

---

Original answer:

Not quite sure if I understand the example code, but if you want to remove all key/value pairs in an array based on whether it begins with a letter, you can:

```
$array = [
    'xa' => 1,
    'xb' => 2,
    'yc' => 3,
    'xd' => 4,
];

$filtered_keys = array_filter(array_keys($array), function($k){
    return !($k{0} == 'x');
});

foreach ($filtered_keys as $v) {
    unset($array[$v]);
}
```

https://3v4l.org/6810T

Answer (score 0):

Didn't try to understand your question fully, but maybe this is what you are looking for, give it a try & do modification according to your need

```
$percentage_array = array(
                         'xaa' => 1,
                         'xab' => 1,
                         'xac' => 1,
                         'non' => 1,
                         'sox' => 1);
$pattern = "/^x(.*)/";
$filtered_array = preg_filter($pattern, "$0", array_keys( $percentage_array ));
echo "<pre>";
print_r($filtered_array);
```

Below is the output

```
Array
(
    [0] => xaa
    [1] => xab
    [2] => xac
)
```